Proof based book recommendation for Probability
I'm an electrical engineering student who enjoys pure and rigorous math studies. I took a course on probability, but as usual our professors didn't prove a single theorem and our bibliography is focused on engineering applications.
I would like a recommendation for a "proof based" book (or books) that would give reasonable math explanations and proofs for the propositions and theorems in Probability.
I know that for some of them it is a must to study measure theory before, but I don't mind to dive into more topics in order to achieve a good background.

The best book that I know by far is the book Foundations of Modern Probability by Olav Kallenberg. It can be quite demanding at times, but the proofs are elegant and complete and there is no lack of rigor.


A FIRST COURSE IN PROBABILITY by Sheldon Ross is a good book that covers many aspects of probability theory and is designed for beginners. It has proofs as well as applications and intuition. The only downside is that it doesn't go as deep as advanced central limit theorems such as Lindeberg’s Theorem and other things on that level and deeper.

For basics, Foundations of the Theory of Probability by Kolmogorov could also be a good choice. It covers probability only up to the laws of large numbers, but provides a thorough, in-depth analysis of everything. You may find it very "terse" though.

For all the advanced stuff like Central Limit Theorems and way more - Rick Durrett's book has it all. It starts by defining and proving the measure-theoretic aspects needed later, so you won't need to look elsewhere for that. But the book is really advanced, so may not be a good starting point. At least meke sure you have your Set Theory and Analysis dialed in before. The problems here could also be quite challenging.


I think the best option for you, having an engineering background, it to start with the book 1 and then move over to 3 if you're interested in diving deeper.
